# Add audio visualization overlay to video with FFMpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

Wondering if its possible to add audio visualization to a video.
I've found some filters from this site https://lukaprincic.si/development-log/ffmpeg-audio-visualization-tricks
Most examples seem to be with an image and audio file and not a video file.

I've tried the following but it just yields a video with audio but no visualization.

```
ffmpeg -stream_loop -1 -i cassette-edit.mp4 -i test-audio.mp3 -filter_complex "[1:a]showwaves=s=1920x1080:mode=line:colors=white:draw=full,format=rgba[out]" -shortest -map "[out]" -map 0:v -map 1:a 'Cassette Dreams - w visualizer.mp4' -y
```

Comment: Your command creates 2 video streams, only one you can watch at a time. You probably need to add `colorkey=white` to make your waveform stream to have transparent background and use `[0:v][out]overlay` to overlay the waveform on top of the video.

Comment: Tried the following changes but I get an error 
`[AVFilterGraph @ 0x7fae3fa04980] No output pad can be associated to link label 'out'.
Error initializing complex filters.
Invalid argument`


`ffmpeg -stream_loop -1 -i cassette-edit.mp4 -i test-audio.mp3 -filter_complex "[1:a]showwaves=s=1920x1080:mode=line:colors=white:draw=full;colorkey=white;format=rgba[0:v][out]overlay" -shortest -map "[out]" -map 0:v -map 1:a 'Cassette Dreams - w visualizer.mp4' -y`

Comment: sorry, it was too vague. try the answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
ffmpeg -stream_loop -1 -i cassette-edit.mp4 -i test-audio.mp3 -filter_complex "
    [1:a]showwaves=s=1920x1080:mode=line:colors=white:draw=full[vwave];
    [0:v][vwave]overlay=format=auto[out]
  " -shortest -map "[out]" -map 1:a 'Cassette Dreams - w visualizer.mp4' -y
```

(as a one-liner, removing all extraneous whitespaces)

[edit] no need for `colorkey` as `showwave` appears to output transparent background. Also try `format=auto` option on `overlay`.

Reference: [ffmpeg wiki](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Waveform)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Although no errors, there is no visualization either.

Comment: Did a bit more research, and `colorkey` is not necessary. The FFMpeg wiki example suggests to specify the `format` option on overlay.

Comment: Thanks for the link.. still no cigar. No errors though

Comment: One more thing to try... I forgot to drop `-map [0:v]` from your command. You could very well be looking at the second video feed while the waveform is on the other feed that a video player does not show.

Comment: Tried this but the video won't open, however the screenshot for the video shows what looks like visualization. I think you're onto something. Error mentions it's not compatible with QuickTime (On a mac)
-- opened in VLC with the visualization working

Comment: For the QT compatibility, add `-pix_fmt yuv420p`